# Drawing an OpenGL colored rectangle with different colored vertices

Tags: c++, opengl, colors

I am trying to draw a domino out of 6 white rectangles using GL_QUADS, but because each side is the same color and the vertices are also white it doesn't look 3D.

Below is the code I use for each rectangular side of the Domino:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(100, -25, 100);
glVertex3f(100, -25, -100);
glVertex3f(-100, -25, -100);
glVertex3f(-100, -25, 100);
glEnd();
```

Is there a way of drawing black vertices around each rectangle without changing the color of the rectangle to black?

Comment: If a black outline is what you want. Draw the white block you have now, then draw the block again but in black and use `GL_LINES`.

Comment: Another method involves drawing 2 of the quads in different colors while disabling depth testing.

Comment: Finally, you can look into GLSL shader programming to apply a toon shader on your mesh, which can then be applied to any other mesh you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Just draw it twice, once with white `GL_QUADS`, then once again with black `GL_LINE_LOOP`s.